# How to connect two Firebase projects to one Flutter project for production and staging environments

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, production

Does anyone know how to connect two Firebase projects to one Flutter project? I would like to have one for production data and another for testing/staging data.

The problem that I am running into is that the GoogleService-Info.plist file can't have a unique name so I can only have one of those files.

Has anyone successfully done this or have an easier way to separate the data for environments using Firebase/Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use different Firebase projects for production and staging environments, you have to use [***flavor***](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors).

With flavor, you can define environment-specific configuration for production and staging environments.

Here is [***the tutorial***](https://medium.com/@animeshjain/build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-different-firebase-projects-per-flavor-27c5c5dac10b) on how to set up flavor and configure firebase project for different environments